# How to stop Intellij hiding static constant names by replacing them with random strings?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij keeps replacing final static variable names with random strings. I get that this idea comes from code style/best practices etc., but I find this very annoying. How do I disable this?

E.g. if I create this variable:

```java
private static final Logger logger 
        = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);
```

As soon as I type "logger" and press space/enter, it replaces the name "logger" with some random string e.g. "asdoiasdk"; in the editor it then looks like:

```java
private static final Logger asdoiasdk 
        = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);
```

Screenshots below:

1. I start adding a private static final variable called "logger" - the screenshot shows that state just after I typed the variable name but haven't added " = " yet:

[image: before]

2. Then I press space and equals (" = ") and the variable name changes to this random string "jmeecp":

[image: after]

Comment: disable third party plugins?

Comment: *I get that this idea comes from code style/best practices*: no, using unreadable, meaningless variable names has never been a best practice. You probably have a third party plugin doing that.

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior in 2019.1 and I can't recall seeing this before. So the assumption about third-party plugins is probably correct.

Comment: I am using version: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.7 (Community Edition), Build #IC-182.5107.41, built on November 27, 2018

The only plugins I added are IdeaVim and EnvFile (that injects environment variables)

Comment: I applied the latest update by using "check for updates". I tried by disabled every plugin by going to Settings->Plugins and restarted; same issue. When it starts, the actual variable name is visible; then once it is done doing background jobs ("Indexing..."), the actual name changes to the "masked" name.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot please?

Comment: @yole added screenshots

Comment: Do you have any external programs such as snippet or clipboard managers? There is no logic in IntelliJ that can make such changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why and after having spent a day on this, I'll add the reason in the hope that some other poor soul will benefit from this. Basically, the issue happens if you are using "Fantasque Sans Mono" as your editor font. I think it doesn't play well with the highlighting applied by IntelliJ for typos. E.g.: in the below example, the word "REQUESTSTART" is a typo and thus highlighted by IntelliJ (this font in this screenshot is "Droid Sans Mono"):

[image]

When I change the font to "Fantasque Sans Mono", the issue surfaces:

[image]

There is a pattern between the original string the one shown with this font - the ascii code seems to be going back two positions e.g. R->P, E->C and so on. Very interesting.

Edit 2019-04-15: See [this](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans/issues/108) thread for the workaround that resolved the issue for me.